# Confused with movement in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a small game in pygame. The player is the left hand red rectangle (if you run it) and I am just trying to make the rocket variable move to the left quickly. Whenever I run the program if I press any key or move my mouse it moves the rocket.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame,sys,random
pygame.init()
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 100)
size=width,height=1280,830


screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
black = [0, 0, 0]
white = [255, 255, 255]
sky_blue = ((0,255,255))
red = ((255,0,0))
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",14)
rocket=pygame.Rect(1200,350,150,50)
player= pygame.Rect(250,350,250,50)
hull=100
player_speed=100
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_speed=player_speed+100
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_speed=player_speed-100
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player.top=player.top-50
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player.top=player.top+50

    if player_speed>1000:
        player_speed=1000
    if player_speed<100:
        player_speed=100

    if player.top<0:
        player.top=0
    elif player.bottom>height:
        player.bottom=height
    
    #rocket code
    if player.colliderect(rocket):
        hull=hull-100
    if player_speed>99:
        rocket.right=rocket.right-5
    

screen.fill(sky_blue)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,player)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,rocket)
renderedText = font.render("Speed: "+str(player_speed),1,black)
screen.blit(renderedText, (width/2+50,10))
if hull<1:
    renderedText = font.render("GAME OVER",1,black)
    screen.blit(renderedText, (width/2+500,500))    
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. You have shown us some code and explained what happens when you run it; but *why is that result wrong*? What should happen instead? Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and note that this is *not a discussion forum* - we are not interested in your level of experience, and we also don't do open-ended improvements etc. on code. (For the latter, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com for that; but note they have their own question-asking standards.)

Comment: Please also re-read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code is indented exactly as you actually have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indentation is incorrect which is causing a logic error.

```
if player_speed>1000:

...

rocket.right=rocket.right-5
```

The code between these lines need to be one indent lower. Else this code will only be run when there is a event. Since the for loop will skip execution of any code within if there is no events.